# IBDesignables - Build Failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibdesignable

I'm trying to use some IB Designables I imported into a project, the designables are accessible via storyboard but don't do anything when used. I noticed a

> Designables - Build Failed

under the identity inspector in the top right corner: [image: Designables]

Is there a way to make it so the designables are usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the issue was, I was importing the folder with the designables into the project.  When I took the designables out of the folder and imported them individually it worked fine.

Comment: please explain in more detail. I m facing the same issue.

Comment: Don't bring in the folder that is storing all the designables into the project. Each designable has to be brought into the project individually.

Comment: Got it. I figured it out after 4 hours and saw your comment just. quite a waste of time for a known problem :(

Comment: I added the files from xcode file menu and its still doesn't work.

Comment: @AceN try dragging and dropping each file manually into the project navigator and be sure to check the "copy if needed" option.